# Compare a column with different row and column in sample table using Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle

This is what I am trying to achieve -

Consider below table

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE_TAB
(
COL1  NUMBER,
COL2  NUMBER
)
```

Data is as follows -

```
INSERT INTO sample_tab
VALUES (1 ,3);

INSERT INTO sample_tab
VALUES (3 ,4);

INSERT INTO sample_tab
VALUES (5 ,8)

INSERT INTO sample_tab
VALUES (8 ,12);

INSERT INTO sample_tab
VALUES (13 ,15);

INSERT INTO sample_tab
VALUES (16 ,20);
```

**Actual Data**

```
COL1  COL2
 1     3
 3     4
 5     8
 8     12
 13    15
 16    20
```

If you notice, the data has some overlapping between col2 and col1 example Row 1 Col2 ( data 3) overlaps with Row 2 Col1 (data 3 again), row 3 col2 (data 8) overlaps with row 4 col1 (data 8 again).

If we see such overlaps, we need to combine the over lap and the final output should be as follows

**Expected result**

```
COL1  COL2
 1     4
 5     12
 13    15
 16    20
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks, S.

Comment: look at oracle's analytic functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of the approaches, where we divide source data into logical groups with help of `lag() over()` analytic function, which allows us to reference previous rows in the result set, `case` expression to mark a group and `sum() over()` analytic function to form a group. And finally we extract minimal `col1` and maximal `col2` in a group:

```
with t1 as(
  select col1
       , col2
       , sum(grp) over(order by col1) as grp
    from (select col1
               , col2
               , case 
                   when col1 <> lag(col2) over(order by col1)
                   then 1
                   else 0
                end as grp
           from sample_tab
         )
)
select min(col1) as col1
     , max(col2) as col2
  from t1
 group by grp
 order by col1
```

result:

```
      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         1          4 
         5         12 
        13         15 
        16         20
```